# Unwanted transparent border in tracked scene renders

Tags: rendering

I've been looking how to fix this for a few hours now and nothing seems to work. I'm a beginner to blender. Can provide more info if neccesary. (also it's just a very basic scene for practice)
[image]

Comment: It would be useful to know more about your setup. As it is, it's difficult to analyze anything. Can you share your node setup or the file?